# Swimming - usefulness of different styles with fat

Tags: body-fat, swimming, bellyfat

I am just started to learn swimming... and learnt that there are a large number of styles like Freestyle, breaststoke , backstroke, butterfly stroke ?

Though I just know that each of these strokes have unique advantages, can anyone tell me what is the benefit of each stroke ?

1. which style can be used to reduce the butt fat ?
2. which style can be used to reduce the abdominal fat ?

Thanks in advance for your answers.

Comment: Make sure you avoid [the myth of spot reduction](http://fitness.stackexchange.com/a/3405/1771).

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You can't reduce fat in a particular place. Your genetics determine which places you will gain and loose fat from.

Comment: It might be worth mentioning that building muscle in a particular place can reduce the unsightliness of fat -- though the muscle building process is an exponentially longer one than the fat loss process.

Answer (score 4):

The stroke that will burn the most fat in general is the stroke that allows you to get the most vigorous workout.  Look up some of these questions and answers to get a better understanding of how to implement your swimming program to meet your goals:

1. Regarding why to use different strokes: [Swimming for muscle building and fat burn](https://fitness.stackexchange.com/questions/7802/swimming-for-muscle-building-and-fat-burn)
2. Regarding swimming and calorie burn:
   [Swimming for Fat burn](https://fitness.stackexchange.com/questions/5094/swimming-for-fat-burn)
3. Regarding the idea of spot reduction:
   [How to lose fat only in your thigh?](https://fitness.stackexchange.com/questions/1299/how-to-lose-fat-only-in-your-thigh/3933#3933)
4. Regarding pool running (esp. useful if your swimming stroke is not yet efficient enough to get an intense enough workout: [What is the (a) proper way to pool run?](https://fitness.stackexchange.com/questions/6894/what-is-the-a-proper-way-to-pool-run/6909#6909)
5. Regarding HIIT (high intensity interval training): [Max Heart Rate for HIIT with weights](https://fitness.stackexchange.com/questions/6029/max-heart-rate-for-hiit-with-weights/6032#6032)

Remember that to reduce fat you must also address your diet.